# Plotting cross validation error for different degrees of polynomials

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am new to python and want to plot a CV error for each fold and for each degree of polynomial. The below code calculate error values for different degree polynomials and for each fold. Kindly guide me in this regard.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
kf = KFold(len(dF), n_folds=5)
e_test = []
orders = [2,3]
dims = [6,10]
for i, order in enumerate(orders): 
    dF = getDataByDegree(d,order)
    error = []
    wTemp = np.empty(dims[i])
    wTemp.fill(0.001)
    for train_index, test_index in kf:
        x_train, x_test = dF[train_index], data['l'][train_index]
        y_train, y_test = dF[test_index], data['l'][test_index]
        w, x_error = gradientDes(wTemp,x_train,x_test)
        y_error = errorfun(w,y_train,y_test)
        error.insert(i,y_error[0])
    e_test.insert(i,error) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(1,len(orders):
      ax.plot(orders,values[i],lw=2, label='Test Error - Fold %s' % str(int(i)+1))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for what sklearn calls [validation curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html#validation-curve). The [`validation_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.learning_curve.validation_curve.html) function lets you explore a range of a certain model hyperparameter while doing CV for you.

See [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html) if you want to plot the errors.

Comment: I looked into this earlier, but not sure about taking the mean. Is it the right approach?

Comment: Yes you have to take the mean across all folds for every tested value of the hyperparameter.